# Replace any character in python string

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying something like this:

```
data_01 = "This is an example string Item 03"
if data_01.find("Item %%") != -1:
            data_01 = data_01.replace("Item %%", "")
```

I need to remove any character after "Item", because data_01 string isn't always "Item 03", it can be "Item 4" as an example.

Comment: Hi there.

In order to solve this, you'd first need to explain in much detail what situations can occur in the input.

Comment: Possibly `import re; re.sub(r'(?<=Item)\s\d+', '', data_01)` Check that that "Item" precedes the number and then remove a space + digits after.

Comment: Try this: 

    data_01 = "This is an example string Item 03"
    data_02 = data_01.replace("Item 03", "Item 04")
    print(data_02)

Comment: @Mako212 don't put an answer in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this "Frankenstein" solution helps. It extracts anything in the form of "Item ... " by looking for `Item` then the second group of spaces.

```
def remove_item_and_number(string: str) -> str:
    out = []
    index = string.find("Item")
    if index == -1:
        return string

    out.append(string[:index].strip())

    next_index = index + 4
    non_space_encontered = False
    for i in range(next_index, len(string)):
        if not non_space_encontered and string[i] == " ":
            continue
        else:
            non_space_encontered = True

        if string[i] == " ":
            out.append(string[i:])
            break

    return "".join(out).strip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cases = [
        "This is an example string Item 03",
        "Another item: Item 2, with a comma",
    ]

    for test_case in test_cases:
        print(remove_item_and_number(test_case))

# >> "This is an example string Item 03" -> "This is an example string"
# >> "Another item: Item 2, with a comma" -> "Another item: with a comma"
```